# Coding sonar Plugin 2.13

Tags: java, plugins, sonarqube

Is it possible to obtain rule failures on a resource, during "sensor" or "decorator" stage ? Specifically rule failure ID ?

Maybe it can be obtained on some other stage of batch side, so that it would be possible to generate some additional metrics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do so using the Context object that is given in Decorator#decorate(Resource resource, DecoratorContext context) method.

You can do context#getViolations() to get the violations on the resource.

Note that you should add the following annotation on your decorator class:

> @DependsUpon(DecoratorBarriers.END_OF_VIOLATION_TRACKING)

This will make sure that your decorator gets executed after the violation tracking, so that you have all the violations.